# replace a line in richtextbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, replace, line

I have this code but it have errors , what should i do ?

```
         Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    lines = RichTextBox1.Lines.ToList
    'Dim FilterText = "@"

    For i As Integer = lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        'If (lines(i).Contains(FilterText)) Then
        RichTextBox1.Lines(i) = RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Replace("@", "@sometext")
        'End If
    Next

    RichTextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray
```

Comment: show the error and what you're trying to achieve ???

Comment: RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Replace = "@sometext"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: while the following "works" it does only modify the array which was returned from the `Lines`-property. If you change that array you don't change the text of the TextBox. So you need to re-assign the whole array to the `Lines`-property if you want to change the text(as shown below). So i keep the first part of my answer only because it fixes the syntax not the real issue.

---

It's not

```
RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Replace = "@sometext"
```

but

```
RichTextBox1.Lines(i) =  "@sometext"
```

You can loop the `Lines` forward, the reverse loop is not needed here.

---

Maybe you want to replace all `"@"` with `"@sometext"` instead:

```
RichTextBox1.Lines(i) = RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Replace("@","@sometext")
```

So here the full code necessary (since it still seems to be a problem):

```
Dim newLines As New List(Of String)
For i As Integer = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Length - 1
    newLines.Add(RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Replace("@", "@sometext"))
Next
RichTextBox1.Lines = newLines.ToArray()
```

But maybe you could even use:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("@","@sometext")`
```

---

> because if we have @ abcd this code change it to @ sometextabcd ! I
>   Want a code to replace for example line 1 completely to @ sometext

Please provide all relevant informations in the first place next time:

```
Dim newLines As New List(Of String)
For Each line As String In RichTextBox1.Lines
    Dim newLine = If(line.Contains("@"), "@sometext", line)
    newLines.Add(newLine)
Next
RichTextBox1.Lines = newLines.ToArray()
```

Comment: I trying to replace a line : if Line(x) Contains = @ Replace it with @SomeText :(

Comment: For Each i In RichTextBox1.Lines
            RichTextBox1.Lines(i) = RichTextBox1.Lines(i).Replace("@", "@sometext")
        Next   Whats Wrong ?!

Comment: @MrArman: why do you now use different code? That's wrong because then you don't loop integers but the strings(every line). So `i` is the line and not a number, so you cannot use it in `RichTextBox1.Lines(i)`. You have already the line. But that won't work. You cannot replace the line when you use `For Each`. Your first aproach was correct, But you could loop forward: `For i As Integer = O To lines1.Count - 1 ...`

Comment: Tim , I'm using your full code but it cant replace anything ! I don't know why !!

Comment: @MrArman: what text is in the textbox and what do you want to replace with what?

Comment: I have a rich textbox and in some lines have @ and in want to edit all lines that have @ and replace it with @sometext (sry if my english is bad)

Comment: @MrArman: sorry, it was my fault. I have forgotten that the `Lines` property creates an array that you can change, but you won't change the textbox-text then. You need to reasssign the complete array to this property. I have edited my answer to show you how. The last point stays valid, why don't you simply use `RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Replace("@","@sometext")`?

Comment: because if we have @ abcd this code change it to @ sometextabcd ! I Want a code to replace for example line 1 completely to @ sometext

Comment: @MrArman: ok, now it's clear. Have a look. Now you can even use a `For Each` as shown.